# How to trigger two function on form submit?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a form when the form is submitted i'll call one javascript function and action it to to form handler.

```
<form action="subscribe.php" onsubmit="return form_check(this)" method="post">
<input type="text" value="">
<input type="submit" value="click">
</form>
```

Everything Works fine, Now i want to send the same form fields to another javascript function so i tried like this on submit code

```
    <form action="subscribe.php" 
onsubmit="return (form_check(this) & another_script(this))" method="post">
```

Added **&** in onsubmit but the function is not triggering when the button is clicked. I think this is due to the `action="subscribe.php"` in the form.

I want to send the form value to another javascript function also. how can i achieve this?

Comment: Separate them with a semi-colon, not the ampersand. I'm not sure how it would work if both functions returned something different.

Comment: Which function's value do you want to return?  `form_check` or `another_script`?

Comment: Why isn't `another_script` inside `form_check` function simply?

Comment: @Mike Christensen Thanks i want to execute both function.is that possible?

Comment: in SO one question has a answer not to use double & instead use single & [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11806253/onsubmit-multiple-javascript-functions) @undefined

Comment: This may not be the issue but I think you may be confusing the  [bitwise & operator with the logical && operator](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7310120).

Comment: Keep in mind the `&&` operator won't *necessarily* execute both functions.

Answer (score 1):

With jQuery you can catch the form submit. The `submit` event is sent to an element when the user is attempting to submit a form.

**HTML**

```
<form id="myForm">...</form>
```

**jQuery**

```
$("#myForm").submit(function(event){
  event.preventDefault();

  var this = something;

  myFunctionA(this);
  myFunctionB(this);
});

var myFunctionA = function(this){
  // Function operation
}

var myFunctionB = function(this){
  // Function operation
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There's a few answers depending on what you're trying to do.

If you want to simply *run* both functions and not return anything, you can simply do:

```
onsubmit="form_check(this); another_script(this);"
```

If you want to *always* run `another_script` but *return* the value of `form_check`, you can do:

```
onsubmit="another_script(this); return form_check(this);"
```

If you want to *only* run `another_script` if `form_check` returns `true` (and return true if both `form_check` and `another_script` return `true`), you can do:

```
onsubmit="return form_check(this) && another_script(this);"
```

However, putting too much code in an `onsubmit` handler is usually discouraged.  You should bind event handlers after using the DOM or jQuery.

Comment: Your last example is equivalent to `return (form_check(this) && another_script(this))` since `&&` is a short circuit operator it will not execute `another_script(this)` unless `from_check(this)` returns `true`

Comment: @Austin - That assumes `another_script` always returns true.  It might return `undefined` which would result in different behavior.  I'll make a note of this.

Comment: I would also add that if you want to run both and check both you can do `(form_check(this) & another_script(this))? true : false` or `!!(form_check(this) & another_script(this))`

Answer (score 0):

Does this work?

```
onsubmit="another_script(this); return form_check(this);"
```

of course, it's always better to use unobtrusive event handlers.

Answer (score 0):

```
onsubmit="return ((form_check(this) + another_script(this))===2);"
```

[Demo fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/PcfU8/)