# how to call multiple functions on onSubmit

Tags: javascript

I am trying to call two functions on onSubmit but it is calling only the first function.

following is the code:

```
<form name="reg_indi_form" method="post" onSubmit="return (validate() && req());" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

Comment: see answer how it would be helpful to you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11806253/onsubmit-multiple-javascript-functions?answertab=active#tab-top

Answer (score 0):

In this case `validate()` must return `true` so that `req()` gets executed