# JavaScript name validation not working

Tags: javascript, html, validation

My JavaScript validation function doesn't seem to be working. The same validation format also doesn't seem to be working for my other inputs eg. last name. However, it does work for my email input. I'm creating a webpage and within the full code, I have this JavaScript function for validating the first name, so that the field isn't empty upon submission.

```
function validateFName() {

    var firstname = document.getElementById('firstname').value;
    if( firstname==null || firstname=="")
    {
    alert("Please input a first name");
    }
 }
```

Additionally, below is the input code within the body:

```
<label> First Name: </label> <input type="text" name="firstname"  maxlength="30" placeholder="John" /> <br><br>
```

Below is the calling of the function:

```
<input type="submit" onclick="validateEmail(); validateFName(); validateLName(); validateGender(); validateDate(); validateVName(); validateVEmail();" /> <br>
```

Below is my full code. (Not yet completed)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

  <title>  Truth or Dare </title>


  <style type='text/css'>
    body {
  font: 15px 'Lucida Grande', Verdana, sans-serif;
  color: #404040;
  background: purple;
}

nav {
width: 360px;
height: 70px;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
}

.fancyNav{
    /* Affects the UL element */
    overflow: hidden;
    display: inline-block;
}

.fancyNav li{
    /* Specifying a fallback color and we define CSS3 gradients for the major browsers: */

    background-color: #f0f0f0;
    background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear,left top, left bottom,from(#fefefe), color-stop(0.5,#f0f0f0), color-stop(0.51, #e6e6e6));
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(#fefefe 0%, #f0f0f0 50%, #e6e6e6 51%);
    background-image: -o-linear-gradient(#fefefe 0%, #f0f0f0 50%, #e6e6e6 51%);
    background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(#fefefe 0%, #f0f0f0 50%, #e6e6e6 51%);
    background-image: linear-gradient(#fefefe 0%, #f0f0f0 50%, #e6e6e6 51%);

    border-right: 1px solid rgba(9, 9, 9, 0.125);

    /* Adding a 1px inset highlight for a more polished efect: */

    box-shadow: 1px -1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.6) inset;
    -moz-box-shadow: 1px -1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.6) inset;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 1px -1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.6) inset;

    position:relative;

    float: left;
    list-style: none;
}

.fancyNav li:after{

    /* This creates a pseudo element inslide each LI */ 

    content:'.';
    text-indent:-9999px;
    overflow:hidden;
    position:absolute;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    z-index:1;
    opacity:0;

    /* Gradients! */

    background-image:-webkit-gradient(linear, left top, right top, from(rgba(168,168,168,0.5)),color-stop(0.5,rgba(168,168,168,0)), to(rgba(168,168,168,0.5)));
    background-image:-moz-linear-gradient(left, rgba(168,168,168,0.5), rgba(168,168,168,0) 50%, rgba(168,168,168,0.5));
    background-image:-o-linear-gradient(left, rgba(168,168,168,0.5), rgba(168,168,168,0) 50%, rgba(168,168,168,0.5));
    background-image:-ms-linear-gradient(left, rgba(168,168,168,0.5), rgba(168,168,168,0) 50%, rgba(168,168,168,0.5));
    background-image:linear-gradient(left, rgba(168,168,168,0.5), rgba(168,168,168,0) 50%, rgba(168,168,168,0.5));

    /* Creating borders with box-shadow. Useful, as they don't affect the size of the element. */

    box-shadow:-1px 0 0 #a3a3a3,-2px 0 0 #fff,1px 0 0 #a3a3a3,2px 0 0 #fff;
    -moz-box-shadow:-1px 0 0 #a3a3a3,-2px 0 0 #fff,1px 0 0 #a3a3a3,2px 0 0 #fff;
    -webkit-box-shadow:-1px 0 0 #a3a3a3,-2px 0 0 #fff,1px 0 0 #a3a3a3,2px 0 0 #fff;

    /* This will create a smooth transition for the opacity property */

    -moz-transition:0.25s all;
    -webkit-transition:0.25s all;
    -o-transition:0.25s all;
    transition:0.25s all;
}

/* Treating the first LI and li:after elements separately */

.fancyNav li:first-child{
    border-radius: 4px 0 0 4px;
}

.fancyNav li:first-child:after,
.fancyNav li.selected:first-child:after{
    box-shadow:1px 0 0 #a3a3a3,2px 0 0 #fff;
    -moz-box-shadow:1px 0 0 #a3a3a3,2px 0 0 #fff;
    -webkit-box-shadow:1px 0 0 #a3a3a3,2px 0 0 #fff;

    border-radius:4px 0 0 4px;
}

.fancyNav li:last-child{
    border-radius: 0 4px 4px 0;
}

/* Treating the last LI and li:after elements separately */

.fancyNav li:last-child:after,
.fancyNav li.selected:last-child:after{
    box-shadow:-1px 0 0 #a3a3a3,-2px 0 0 #fff;
    -moz-box-shadow:-1px 0 0 #a3a3a3,-2px 0 0 #fff;
    -webkit-box-shadow:-1px 0 0 #a3a3a3,-2px 0 0 #fff;

    border-radius:0 4px 4px 0;
}

.fancyNav li:hover:after,
.fancyNav li.selected:after,
.fancyNav li:target:after{
    /* This property triggers the CSS3 transition */
    opacity:1;
}

.fancyNav:hover li.selected:after,
.fancyNav:hover li:target:after{
    /* Hides the targeted li when we are hovering on the UL */
    opacity:0;
}

.fancyNav li.selected:hover:after,
.fancyNav li:target:hover:after{
    opacity:1 !important;
}

/* Styling the anchor elements */

.fancyNav li a{
    color: #5d5d5d;
    display: inline-block;
    font: 20px/1 Lobster,Arial,sans-serif;
    padding: 12px 35px 14px;
    position: relative;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.6);
    z-index:2;
    text-decoration:none !important;
    white-space:nowrap;
}

.fancyNav a.homeIcon{
    background:url('home.png') no-repeat center center;
    display: block;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding-left: 12px;
    padding-right: 12px;
    text-indent: -9999px;
    width: 16px;
}
h2{
    color: blue;
    font-size: 20px;
}
input {
  padding: 5px;
    font-size: 15px;
    text-shadow: 0px 1px 0px #fff;
    outline: none;
    -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
    -moz-border-radius: 3px;
    border-radius: 3px;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    -webkit-transition: .3s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: .3s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: .3s ease-in-out;
}

    input:focus {
        border: 1px solid #fafafa;
        -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 6px #007eff;
        -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px #007eff;
        box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px #007eff;
    }


label{

  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
  font-size: 100%;
  font: inherit;
  vertical-align: baseline;
}

#box {
  width: 430px; margin: 60px auto; padding: 60px 30px;
    background: white; border: 1px solid #e1e1e1;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 8px #444;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 8px #444;
}


h1 {
    font-size: 20px; 
    color: #445668; 
    text-transform: uppercase;
    text-align: center; 
    margin: 0 0 35px 0; 
    text-shadow: 0px 1px 0px #f2f2f2;
}
  </style>



<script type='text/javascript'>

function validateEmail() {

    var email = document.getElementById('email').value;
    if( email==null || email=="")
    {
    alert("Please input an email address");
    }
 }

function validateFName() {

    var firstname = document.getElementById('firstname').value;
    if( firstname==null || firstname=="")
    {
    alert("Please input a first name");
    }
 }

    function validateLName() {

    var lastname = document.getElementById('lastname').value;
    if( lastname==null || lastname=="")
    {
    alert("Please input a last name");
    }
 }

        function validateGender() {

    var gender = document.getElementById('gender').value;
    if( gender==null || gender=="")
    {
    alert("Please select a gender");
    }
 }


        function validateDate() {

    var date = document.getElementById('date').value;
    if( date==null || date=="")
    {
    alert("Please select a date");
    }
 }


        function validateVName() {

    var vname = document.getElementById('vname').value;
    if( vname==null || vname=="")
    {
    alert("Please input a victim's name");
    }
 }

 function validateVEmail() {

    var vemail = document.getElementById('vemail').value;
    if( vemail==null || vemail=="")
    {
    alert("Please input a victim's email");
    }
 }

</script>


</head>
<body>
<div id="navi">
  <nav>
<ul class="fancyNav">
         <li id="home"><a href="#home" class="homeIcon">Home</a></li>
         <li id="news"><a href="#truth">TRUTH</a></li>
         <li id="about"><a href="#Dare">DARE</a></li>
     </ul>
  </nav>
  </div>

<div id="box">
<form id="truth">

<h1> Truth </h1>
<label> First Name: </label> <input type="text" name="firstname"  maxlength="30" placeholder="John" /> <br><br>
<label> Last Name: </label> <input type="text" name="lastname"  maxlength="30" placeholder="Doe" /> <br><br>
<label> Email:</label> <input type="text" id="email" /> <br><br>
<label> Male </label><input type="radio" name="gender" value="male"/>
<label> Female </label><input type="radio" name="gender" value="female"/> <br><br>
<label> Date to be performed: </label><input type="date" name="date"/><br><br>
<h2> Victim </h2>
<label> Name: </label>  <input type="text" name="vname"  maxlength="30" /><br><br>
 <label> Email:</label> <input type="text" id="vemail" /> <br><br>


    <h2> Please select a truth questions below </h2> <br>
<input type="radio" name="truth" value="q1"> Have you ever fallen and landed on your head? <br>

  <input type="radio"  name="truth" value="q2"> Have you ever return too much change? <br>

  <input type="radio" name="truth" value="q3"> Have you ever been admitted into the hospital? <br>

  <input type="radio" name="truth" value="q4"> Have you ever baked a cake? <br>

  <input type="radio" name="truth" value="q5"> Have you ever cheated on test? <br>

  <input type="radio" name="truth" value="q6"> Did you ever wish you were never born? <br>

  <input type="radio" name="truth" value="q7"> Did you ever hide from Sunday School? <br><br>

<input type="submit" onclick="validateEmail(); validateFName(); validateLName(); validateGender(); validateDate(); validateVName(); validateVEmail();" /> <br>
</form>
</div>

</body>


</html>
```

Comment: check this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11806429/3419997)

Comment: The issue is actually with the id attribute.

Comment: the only element have id are email and vemail

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you say document.getElementById("firstname"), your html tag should be like:

```
input type="text" id="firstname" name="firstname"
```

You forgot to give "id" attribute to the element. "name"attribute will be used to get the values on server side when you post/submit the form.

Answer (score 0):

You have not given the ID to your element Input  either give an ID or change the method to

> getElementsByTagName("firstName");

Answer (score 0):

Add **`id="firstname"`** to perform work perfectly because is this not exist in input field so can not find **`getElementById('firstname')`** not find this element,

```
<label> First Name: </label> <input type="text" name="firstname"  maxlength="30" placeholder="John" id="firstname"/>
```

#### View <kbd>[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gam51k1d/)</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

To be sure, make a habit of adding name and id to your inputs

```
<input type='text' id='firstName' name='firstName'>
```

Comment: please remove the part of "if your button is a submit..." because it's not true... if you add `return false` in your function or `e.preventDefault` then it will be considered for sure...

Comment: ...and comment here once you changed it and i'll be happy to remove my downvote...

Answer (score 0):

Since you specifically tagged [html5](/questions/tagged/html5) [validation](/questions/tagged/validation) and based on your validation requirements from your Javascript code, I think using HTML 5 form validation feature would be a better bit for you. Thus, reducing the effort of coding in Javascript.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Truth or Dare</title>
  <style type='text/css'>
    body {
      font: 15px'Lucida Grande', Verdana, sans-serif;
      color: #404040;
      background: purple;
    }
    nav {
      width: 360px;
      height: 70px;
      margin-left: auto;
      margin-right: auto;
    }
    .fancyNav {
      /* Affects the UL element */
      overflow: hidden;
      display: inline-block;
    }
    .fancyNav li {
      /* Specifying a fallback color and we define CSS3 gradients for the major browsers: */
      background-color: #f0f0f0;
      background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#fefefe), color-stop(0.5, #f0f0f0), color-stop(0.51, #e6e6e6));
      background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(#fefefe 0%, #f0f0f0 50%, #e6e6e6 51%);
      background-image: -o-linear-gradient(#fefefe 0%, #f0f0f0 50%, #e6e6e6 51%);
      background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(#fefefe 0%, #f0f0f0 50%, #e6e6e6 51%);
      background-image: linear-gradient(#fefefe 0%, #f0f0f0 50%, #e6e6e6 51%);
      border-right: 1px solid rgba(9, 9, 9, 0.125);
      /* Adding a 1px inset highlight for a more polished efect: */
      box-shadow: 1px -1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.6) inset;
      -moz-box-shadow: 1px -1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.6) inset;
      -webkit-box-shadow: 1px -1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.6) inset;
      position: relative;
      float: left;
      list-style: none;
    }
    .fancyNav li:after {
      /* This creates a pseudo element inslide each LI */
      content: '.';
      text-indent: -9999px;
      overflow: hidden;
      position: absolute;
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
      top: 0;
      left: 0;
      z-index: 1;
      opacity: 0;
      /* Gradients! */
      background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, right top, from(rgba(168, 168, 168, 0.5)), color-stop(0.5, rgba(168, 168, 168, 0)), to(rgba(168, 168, 168, 0.5)));
      background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(left, rgba(168, 168, 168, 0.5), rgba(168, 168, 168, 0) 50%, rgba(168, 168, 168, 0.5));
      background-image: -o-linear-gradient(left, rgba(168, 168, 168, 0.5), rgba(168, 168, 168, 0) 50%, rgba(168, 168, 168, 0.5));
      background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(left, rgba(168, 168, 168, 0.5), rgba(168, 168, 168, 0) 50%, rgba(168, 168, 168, 0.5));
      background-image: linear-gradient(left, rgba(168, 168, 168, 0.5), rgba(168, 168, 168, 0) 50%, rgba(168, 168, 168, 0.5));
      /* Creating borders with box-shadow. Useful, as they don't affect the size of the element. */
      box-shadow: -1px 0 0 #a3a3a3, -2px 0 0 #fff, 1px 0 0 #a3a3a3, 2px 0 0 #fff;
      -moz-box-shadow: -1px 0 0 #a3a3a3, -2px 0 0 #fff, 1px 0 0 #a3a3a3, 2px 0 0 #fff;
      -webkit-box-shadow: -1px 0 0 #a3a3a3, -2px 0 0 #fff, 1px 0 0 #a3a3a3, 2px 0 0 #fff;
      /* This will create a smooth transition for the opacity property */
      -moz-transition: 0.25s all;
      -webkit-transition: 0.25s all;
      -o-transition: 0.25s all;
      transition: 0.25s all;
    }
    /* Treating the first LI and li:after elements separately */
    .fancyNav li:first-child {
      border-radius: 4px 0 0 4px;
    }
    .fancyNav li:first-child:after,
    .fancyNav li.selected:first-child:after {
      box-shadow: 1px 0 0 #a3a3a3, 2px 0 0 #fff;
      -moz-box-shadow: 1px 0 0 #a3a3a3, 2px 0 0 #fff;
      -webkit-box-shadow: 1px 0 0 #a3a3a3, 2px 0 0 #fff;
      border-radius: 4px 0 0 4px;
    }
    .fancyNav li:last-child {
      border-radius: 0 4px 4px 0;
    }
    /* Treating the last LI and li:after elements separately */
    .fancyNav li:last-child:after,
    .fancyNav li.selected:last-child:after {
      box-shadow: -1px 0 0 #a3a3a3, -2px 0 0 #fff;
      -moz-box-shadow: -1px 0 0 #a3a3a3, -2px 0 0 #fff;
      -webkit-box-shadow: -1px 0 0 #a3a3a3, -2px 0 0 #fff;
      border-radius: 0 4px 4px 0;
    }
    .fancyNav li:hover:after,
    .fancyNav li.selected:after,
    .fancyNav li:target:after {
      /* This property triggers the CSS3 transition */
      opacity: 1;
    }
    .fancyNav:hover li.selected:after,
    .fancyNav:hover li:target:after {
      /* Hides the targeted li when we are hovering on the UL */
      opacity: 0;
    }
    .fancyNav li.selected:hover:after,
    .fancyNav li:target:hover:after {
      opacity: 1 !important;
    }
    /* Styling the anchor elements */
    .fancyNav li a {
      color: #5d5d5d;
      display: inline-block;
      font: 20px/1 Lobster, Arial, sans-serif;
      padding: 12px 35px 14px;
      position: relative;
      text-shadow: 1px 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.6);
      z-index: 2;
      text-decoration: none !important;
      white-space: nowrap;
    }
    .fancyNav a.homeIcon {
      background: url('home.png') no-repeat center center;
      display: block;
      overflow: hidden;
      padding-left: 12px;
      padding-right: 12px;
      text-indent: -9999px;
      width: 16px;
    }
    h2 {
      color: blue;
      font-size: 20px;
    }
    input {
      padding: 5px;
      font-size: 15px;
      text-shadow: 0px 1px 0px #fff;
      outline: none;
      -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
      -moz-border-radius: 3px;
      border-radius: 3px;
      border: 1px solid #ccc;
      -webkit-transition: .3s ease-in-out;
      -moz-transition: .3s ease-in-out;
      -o-transition: .3s ease-in-out;
    }
    input:focus {
      border: 1px solid #fafafa;
      -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 6px #007eff;
      -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px #007eff;
      box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px #007eff;
    }
    label {
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
      border: 0;
      font-size: 100%;
      font: inherit;
      vertical-align: baseline;
    }
    #box {
      width: 430px;
      margin: 60px auto;
      padding: 60px 30px;
      background: white;
      border: 1px solid #e1e1e1;
      -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 8px #444;
      -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 8px #444;
    }
    h1 {
      font-size: 20px;
      color: #445668;
      text-transform: uppercase;
      text-align: center;
      margin: 0 0 35px 0;
      text-shadow: 0px 1px 0px #f2f2f2;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="navi">
    <nav>
      <ul class="fancyNav">
        <li id="home"><a href="#home" class="homeIcon">Home</a>

        </li>
        <li id="news"><a href="#truth">TRUTH</a>

        </li>
        <li id="about"><a href="#Dare">DARE</a>

        </li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </div>
  <div id="box">
    <form id="truth">

      <h1> Truth </h1>

      <label>First Name:</label>
      <input type="text" nam e="firstname" maxlength="30" placeholder="John" required="required" />
      <br>
      <br>
      <label>Last Name:</label>
      <input type="text" name="lastname" maxlength="30" placeholder="Doe" required="required" />
      <br>
      <br>
      <label>Email:</label>
      <input type="email" id="email" required="required" />
      <br>
      <br>
      <label>Male</label>
      <input type="radio" name="gender" value="male" required="required" />
      <label>Female</label>
      <input type="radio" name="gender" value="female" required="required" />
      <br>
      <br>
      <label>Date to be performed:</label>
      <input type="date" name="date" required="required" />
      <br>
      <br>

      <h2> Victim </h2>

      <label>Name:</label>
      <input type="text" name="vname" maxlength="30" required="required" />
      <br>
      <br>
      <label>Email:</label>
      <input type="email" id="vemail" required="required" />
      <br>
      <br>
      <h2> Please select a truth questions below </h2> 
      <br>
      <input type="radio" name="truth" value="q1">Have you ever fallen and landed on your head?
      <br>
      <input type="radio" name="truth" value="q2">Have you ever return too much change?
      <br>
      <input type="radio" name="truth" value="q3">Have you ever been admitted into the hospital?
      <br>
      <input type="radio" name="truth" value="q4">Have you ever baked a cake?
      <br>
      <input type="radio" name="truth" value="q5">Have you ever cheated on test?
      <br>
      <input type="radio" name="truth" value="q6">Did you ever wish you were never born?
      <br>
      <input type="radio" name="truth" value="q7">Did you ever hide from Sunday School?
      <br>
      <br>
      <input type="submit" />
      <br>
    </form>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I wish I could do that but we are required to use JavaScript for all validations.