# JavaScript and VBScript function calling

Tags: javascript

HTML Form:

```html
<form 
    name="CheckIn" 
    method="post" 
    action="check.asp" 
    onsubmit="return CheckBreakTime()  && CheckTime();" 
>
```

I call two functions whit onsubmit,the functions return true or false,but function works only if it's "first" ,for example if i say ' `onsubmit="return CheckTime() && CheckBreakTime();"` ' only CheckTime works if i call ChecKBreakTime first it only works.

The Functions *(JavaScript)* :

```js
function CheckBreakTime(){
    if (document.getElementById('breakco').checked) {
        var BKTimeDif1 = '<%=BTimeDif%>';
        var var1 = 20 ;
        var sum1 = var1 - BKTimeDif1 ;
        if (BKTimeDif1 > 10 && BKTimeDif1 < 21) {
            alert("You were on a break longer than 10 minutes,You must wait " + sum1 + " minutes to pass to check out from break. ");
            return false;
        } else {
            return true;
        }
    } 

    else {
        return true;  
        }
    }

function CheckTime() {
    if (document.getElementById('breakci').checked) {
        var TimeDif2 = '<%=BTimeDiff%>';
        var TimeDif1 = '<%=TimeDif%>';
        if (TimeDif1 < 120) {
            alert("You must work at least two hours before you can go on a break.");
            return false;
        } else {
            if (TimeDif2 != 0 && TimeDif2 < 120) {
                alert("You must work at least two hours before you can go on another break.");
                return false;
            }
            else {
                return true;
            }
        }


    }
    else {
        return true;
    }
}
```

and the VBScript code that i put in JavaScript:

```
Dim TimeDif
TimeDif=Round(Csng(DateDiff("n", (HourList.Fields.Item("checkInTime").Value), (Now()))), 2)
Dim BTimeDif
If Not IsNull(HourList.Fields.Item("breakCheckIn").Value) Then
BTimeDif = Round(Csng(DateDiff("n", (HourList.Fields.Item("breakCheckIn").Value), (Now()))), 2)
End If
If Not IsNull(HourList.Fields.Item("breakCheckOut").Value) Then    
Dim BTimeDiff
BTimeDiff = Round(Csng(DateDiff("n", (HourList.Fields.Item("breakCheckOut").Value), (Now()))), 2)
End If
```

VBScript code works fine,it returns what it need to and JavaScript gets it.Can some tell me what is the problem...

Comment: If your server side vbs is correctly populating the values of TimeDif and BTimeDif then can I suggest that this is a javascript question and it doesn't need the other two tags?

Comment: You are comparing numbers to strings in CheckTime.

Comment: The problem was that i check buttons that are not displayed because of vbscript,so the javascript just check the first one.The answer is to put hidden inputs whit same id. Sorry if i offended,sorry for my bad grammar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want both functions to run even if the first one evaluates to false - then you can use "&":
[onsubmit multiple javascript functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11806253/onsubmit-multiple-javascript-functions)

But, personally I'd wrap them both in a function that aggregates the logic of both:

```
function checkBothTimes(){
  if (!CheckBreakTime()){
    return false;
  }
  else if (!CheckTime()){
    return false;
  }
  return true;
}
```

Even though this is longer - it makes the code easier to read (to me).

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript uses [short-circuit evaluation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators#Short-Circuit_Evaluation) for its logical operators. That means that in an expression like `expr1 && expr2`, `expr2` is evaluated only if `expr1` evaluates to true. If `expr1` evaluates to false there is no need to evaluate `expr2`, since the result of `expr1 && expr2` will be to false no matter what.

So, if you run for example

```
var result = foo() && bar();

function foo(){
  console.log("running foo!");
  return false;
}

function bar(){
  console.log("running bar!");
  return false;
}
```

Only function `foo()` will be executed. This is effectively the same as:

```
var result = foo();
if (result){
  result = bar();
}
```

That's why only the first function in your expression gets called. If it returns false, there's no need to run the second one.