# How to post form and store data into session storage together

Tags: javascript, html, forms, form-submit

I am fairly new to HTML and JavaScript and I wanted to create a form and let user to fill in data. After pressing submit button, the form should be posting the form data to formspree.io and store into session storage together. But the problem is I can't do it both together. Is there any way to fix this? Thank you.

HTML

```
<form id="formset" class="main_form" action="https://formspree.io/[post-id]" method="POST">
                        <div class="row">
                           <div class="col-md-12 ">
                              <input class="contactus" placeholder="Full Name" type="text" id="fullname">
                           </div>
                           <div class="col-md-7">
                              <input class="contactus" placeholder="Email" type="tel" id="email">
                           </div>
                           <div class="col-md-7">
                              <input class="contactus" placeholder="Phone Number" type="text" id="phonenumber">
                           </div>
                           <div class="col-md-12">
                              <textarea class="contactus1" placeholder="Message" type="text" id="message"></textarea>
                           </div>
                           <div class="col-md-12">
                              <button class="send_btn" type="submit" id="submitform">Send</button>
                           </div>
                        </div>
                     </form>
```

p.s. the form ID of formspree is censored.

JavaScript

```
$(function() {
    $("form").submit(function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        sessionStorage.clear();
        var fullname = $("#fullname").val();
        var email = $("#email").val();
        var phonenumber = $("#phonenumber").val();
        var message = $("#message").val();
        console.log(fullname);
        var dataset = {
            fullname,
            email,
            phonenumber,
            message
        }

        sessionStorage.setItem('formcontent', JSON.stringify(dataset));
        
    });
});
```

Comment: From what I understood, you would like to `POST` the form's data into an API and at the same time or right after that (concurrently) you would like to somewhere else. Why do you say you cannot do it? Are you getting some error? Have you tried adding an `onClick` event handler to trigger a function?

Comment: @TheDaniel can't seem to use action and onClick together.

Comment: I see, you may need to modify your code a bit to make it more flexible if you want to accomplish what you need. Take a look into [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11806429/4750980). You might want to think if this approach is the want you want to take. There are multiple ways of submitting form data, using `onClick` allows you to bind the button to a function and that will give you much more flexibility, so you can send data to a database along with other things.

Comment: @TheDaniel thank you, the post was very informative.